# Change initial view controller swift

Tags: swift, appdelegate

I need to change the initial view controller based on whether voiceover is on or not. I have tried multiple ways but I always get the same error: "Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'window'"
This is what I have in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
    print("voiceover: \(voiceOver)") // prints if voice over is on

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "voiceoverViewController")

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'window'

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare a `window` property manually:

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

`UIApplicationDelegate` is just a protocol, it doesn't declare any properties for you.

Comment: Thanks!, my code now runs, but it is not opening the view controller I have specified

Comment: @KieranWaugh Remove the main storyboard from your plist.

Comment: unfortunately it is still not opening to the specified view controller

Comment: @KieranWaugh Are you sure the code is run? Is there `@UIApplicationMain` attribute on top of your `AppDelegate`?

Comment: I think its because I am using swift 5 and IOS 13, however I still do not know how to fix the problem, thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the view controller marked as 'initial viewcontroller' in your storyboard?

Comment: @Koen no, as the viewcontroller is to be only opened when the device has voiceover activated

Comment: @Koen The same should work on Swift 5 and iOS 13. Did you check whether your code is run?

Comment: I have tried moving the code to sceneDelegate 'willCOnnectTo'  but it just shows a blank screen now when run

Comment: @KieranWaugh I your moved the code then don't reassign `window` and don't call `makeKeyAndVisible`.

Answer (score 2):

**You don't have to declare window variable manually**

It is available in **SceneDelegate** file in your project

It will have pre defined method :

> func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession,
>   options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)

**Example**

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession,
 options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {          
        self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene) 
        let initialViewController = 
            storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "voiceoverViewController")            
        self.window!.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```